# Закрасить строку , если в ячейке столбца слово заканчивается на нужную букву

Tags: excel, office, excel-формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как задать правило в условном форматирование, чтобы в столбце "Адміністративний центр", если слово заканчивалось на букву "а", то закрашивался весь рядок зеленым, как это можно выполнить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Закладка *Главная-Условное форматирование-Создать правило-Использовать формулу*

```
=ПРАВБ($F1)="а"
```

Задать диапазон форматирования - столбцы `A:H` (или выделить эти столбцы перед созданием правила).